# Python - Inherited methods break when overriding __init__

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I have a geometric base class `ExtrudedSurface` and a child class `Cylinder`, which is a 'kind of' extruded surface.
The base class has a method to `translate` itself (not in-place) by constructing a modified version of itself.

I would like to re-use this method by the child class `Cylinder`, and have it return a new, translated `Cylinder`. However, as implemented now this does not work because `Cylinder` has a different `__init__` signature which is called in `translate`.

What is the best way to achieve this? How can `Cylinder` use the inherited method `translate` and return a new `Cylinder` object?

EDIT 1: I think it has to do with LSP violation but I'm not sure.

```py
class ExtrudedSurface:
    def __init__(self, profile: Curve, direction: Vector, length: float):
        """
        An extruded surface geometry created by sweeping a 3D 'profile' curve along a 
        'direction' for a given 'length'.
        """

        self.profile = profile
        self.direction = direction.normalize()
        self.length = length

    def translate(self, translation: Vector) -> ExtrudedSurface:
        """Return a translated version of itself."""

        return self.__class__(
            self.profile.translate(translation),
            self.length,
            self.direction
        )



class Cylinder(ExtrudedSurface):
    def __init__(self, point: Point, direction: Vector, radius: float, length: float):
        """Cylinder surface.

        Args:
            point: Center point of extruded circle.
            direction: Direction vector of the cylinder (axis).
            radius: Cylinder radius.
            length: Extrusion length in 'direction'.
        """

        direction = direction.normalize()

        profile = Circle(point, direction, radius)

        super().__init__(profile, direction, length)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "this does not work"? What do you get by running that? Any exception? Do you have any executable example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short story short: the by-the-book approach there is to override the `translate()` method, as well, and call the updated constructor from there.

Now, you can refactor your class initialization and separate attribute setting from other needed actions, and then create a new class-method to clone an instance with all the attributes from a first instance, and just call this initialization, if needed.

If no initialization is needed, just a "clone" method is needed. If you happen to call this method `__copy__`, then you can use the `copy.copy` call for that, which is almost as if it was an operator in Python, and it can, by itself, have value for your end-users.

Moreover -- if your class requires no initialization besides setting plain attributes, and no calculations at all, `copy.copy` will just work out of the box with your instances - no extra `__copy__` method needed:

```
from copy import copy

class ExtrudedSurface:
    def __init__(self, profile: Curve, direction: Vector, length: float):
        """
        An extruded surface geometry created by sweeping a 3D 'profile' curve along a 
        'direction' for a given 'length'.
        """

        self.profile = profile
        self.direction = direction.normalize()
        self.length = length

    def translate(self, translation: Vector) -> ExtrudedSurface:
        """Return a translated version of itself."""

        new_profile = self.profile.translate(translation)
        new_instance = copy(self)
        new_instance.profile = new_profile
        return new_instance
     


class Cylinder(ExtrudedSurface):

    def __init__(self, point: Point, direction: Vector, radius: float, length: float):
        ...
```

Just attempt to the fact that `copy` will not recursively copy the attributes, so, if the `self.direction` vector is a mutable object in the framework you are using, this will keep both clones bound to the same vector, and if it changes in the original, that change will be reflected in the clone. By the nature of your code I am assuming everything is immutable there and all transforms create new instances: then this will work. Otherwise, you should also copy the original `.direction` attribute into the new instance.

In time: yes, that is an LSP violation - but I always think that LSP is given more importance than it should when it come to practical matters.

The more generic code I described, should your initialization be more complex would be:

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self, base_args):
        #code to set initial attributes
        ...
        # call inner init with possible sideeffects:
        self.inner_init()
    
    def inner_init(self):
        # code with side effects (like, attaching instance to a container)
        # should be written in order to be repeat-proof - calls on the same instance have no effect
        ...

   def __copy__(self):
      new_instance = self.__class__.new()  
      new_instance.__dict__.update(self.__dict__)
      self.inner_init()
```

Comment: Thank you, I will give this a try. That's right, overriding `translate` is always an option, but that largely defeats the purpose of subclassing for me in this instance. I have multiple similar methods like `symmetry`, `rotate`, `transform`, etc.

Comment: Yes, everything is immutable (although not enforced) in this framework.

Comment: if there is no extra code to the instances, plain calling `copy.copy` as shown in the first part will work out of the box.

Comment: Just to clarify, if my classes have derived attributes (calculated from inputs like `profile`), those should be set in `inner_init`, and finally `inner_init` gets called after updating the attributes of the copied instance in `translate`, correct?

Comment: to the contrary if they are like in the example: here you pre-calculate values from the arguments in init, and set a common attribute in set_profile - the universal "copy" method should copy the post-calculated attribute. If they, on the other hand, have an attribute that will be calculated equal for all subclasses, that could go in inner init (say, you had an `.normalized_direction` in this case).

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not following. In `translate`, you create a translated profile, make an instance copy, and then assign the new profile. Where does the derived attribute (e.g. profile center) based on the new profile happen?

Comment: If there are attributes that will always be calculated from others, you can make use of Python's `property` instead of pre-calculating all of then on `init`. Otherwise, if the way some attributes derive from others will vary from class to class, that code should go into the "inner_init".

Comment: Right, I suppose I can use `property` for those cases. On another note, in your example, when a `Cylinder` is translated, its attribute `point` (which is defined as the cylinder center) will be out of date i.e. it is not translated, breaking that class' invariant. I don't think there is a way around it anytime you're editing attributes directly.